# Custom format file and subfiles

Tags: format-files, subfiles, performance

I want to use a custom format file to speed up my compilation. However this doesn't play together with the [subfiles](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) package.

Consider the following minimal example:

`preamble.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%further packages and custom commands
```

From this I can create a custom format using

```
pdflatex -ini -jobname="preamble" "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"
```

The other files are:

`main.tex`

```
\begin{document}

Here are the contents of my subfile:

\subfile{sub}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this works via:

```
pdflatex -fmt preamble main.tex
```

`sub.tex`

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

However compiling this via

```
pdflatex -fmt preamble sub.tex
```

doesn't work and gives the error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass[main]{
                         subfiles}
?
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Maybe you can get it to work with the standalone package instead of subfiles? With the standalone package, preambles of included files are ignored

Comment: But how can I make a standalone file use the same preamble as the main file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> pdflatex -fmt preamble sub.tex

The error is self-explanatory: In this way you provide two `\documentclass`, that is not the same that left to the `subfile` class to be replaced by  the (non-existent in this case) document class of `main.tex`. This is the same that compile a single file with this **wrong** code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}  
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The possible solutions:

1) Left `\documentclass` in  `main.tex`. Then, the problem will be that in `preamble.tex` there are `\usepackage` commands that  must be used  *after* the `\documentclass` (of main.tex), not before. Fortunately this command can be replaced by `\RequirePackage`. So, this `preamble.tex` produce a working  `preamble.fmt`

```
\RequirePackage{subfiles}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
%%further packages and custom commands
```

The `main.tex` should be then:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % 
\begin{document}
Here are the contents of my subfile: 
\subfile{sub}
\end{document}
```

2) Alternatively, in case of trouble with some code, resign to a non-precompiled preamble (fused in `main.tex`  or included with  `\input{preamble}`).

3) If the precompiled preamble is indispensable (=noticeable seep up), in case of trouble I guess that should be possible use a mix of both approaches (that is, a pre-compiled/pre-document preamble plus the  conventional non-precompiled/post-document preamble with the problematic  code). However, this look like the typical situations in which I regret ignore the KISS principle ("Keep it simple, stupid").

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the docmute package to the preamble format file instead of subfiles, and a regular article class in the sub file. the problem is that latex only allows one documentclass per document, and you are adding a second in the subfile; docmute redefines the documentclass command and the document environment, so that the preambles of the included files are ignored. so, using docmute and standard include should solve the problem

Comment: Isn't this too generic to be an answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/91803)

Comment: I have added some explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with two format files, one with the `subfiles` document class and one with `article`. As the error message says, you can't have two `documentclass` statements in a single file — having one in your custom format file counts!